Does it matter if there's a gap in partition offset numbers when resizing the Windows 10 recovery partition?
A PC  was set up for me a few years ago at a company for which I do some part-time consulting work, though they expect me to take care of doing the Windows updates for it. It has a gap in the partition numbers: there's a disk 0 partion 2 and a disk 0 partition 4.  A recent security update requires the recovery partition to have 250MB free space and I'm going to have to enlarge it. Will the "gap" in the partition numbers present problems for that process?


There is no "gap". Disk 0 partition 3 is your C: drive, the volume list just shows it before other disks as it is the system partition.

Thanks.  So the disks are numbered with zero-based offset and the partition numbering starts at 1?

Non-consecutive partition numbers is absolutely normal.
The number of the partition denotes its position
inside the partition-table, starting with 1.
New partitions are usually added at the end of the table, so the entries
of deleted partitions will stay empty.
In your case, the entry for partition 1 is empty and missing, while
partition 3 is the C: partition.
